# Import socketio fails inside a docker containers?

Tags: python, docker, socket.io

I've built a docker image, each container that use such image will run an application called 'run.py'.

run.py uses socket.io: `import socketio`

I obtain the following error after the docker run:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 1, in <module>
    import socketio
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/socketio/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .zmq_manager import ZmqManager
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/socketio/zmq_manager.py", line 5, in <module>
    import eventlet.green.zmq as zmq
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from eventlet import convenience
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/convenience.py", line 6, in <module>
    from eventlet.green import socket
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/green/socket.py", line 21, in <module>
    from eventlet.support import greendns
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/support/greendns.py", line 69, in <module>
    setattr(dns.rdtypes.IN, pkg, import_patched('dns.rdtypes.IN.' + pkg))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/support/greendns.py", line 59, in import_patched
    return patcher.import_patched(module_name, **modules)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/patcher.py", line 119, in import_patched
    *additional_modules + tuple(kw_additional_modules.items()))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/patcher.py", line 93, in inject
    module = __import__(module_name, {}, {}, module_name.split('.')[:-1])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/support/dns/rdtypes/IN/WKS.py", line 24, in <module>
    _proto_udp = socket.getprotobyname('udp')
socket.error: protocol not found
```

My Dockerfile provides an official python image, it installs the requirements described below and it adds the file protocols in /etc. This last step was done following the advices in https://github.com/eventlet/eventlet/issues/370 .

```
#parent image: official python runtime
FROM python:2.7-slim
#workdir: /app
WORKDIR /app
#copy the current directory contents into the container in the path /app
ADD . /app
ADD protocols /etc
#install packages contained in the text 
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
#make port 80 available to the world (outside the container)
EXPOSE 8081
#execute a py app
CMD ["python", "run.py"]
```

The requirements are:

```
Netbase
python-socketio
eventlet
socketIO-client
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the **slim** version of Python,
use the **full** Python version.

Your dockerfile would then look like this:

```
#parent image: official python runtime
FROM python:2.7
#workdir: /app
WORKDIR /app
#copy the current directory contents into the container in the path /app
ADD . /app
ADD protocols /etc
#install packages contained in the text 
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
#make port 80 available to the world (outside the container)
EXPOSE 8081
#execute a py app
CMD ["python", "run.py"]
```